# Forgot Username / Pwd to CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

Does anyone know how can I reset the username and password for CouchDB ?

Comment: Hope this help :- http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/security.html

Comment: Re-Installing couchDb worked :-)

Comment: You don't have anything important in the existing database?

Comment: Yes, you are right i was just playing around what all options are there in couchDB. Can you please provide few reference/resource i should look to start with,if you have an idea ?

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me:
while couchdb is stopped,

1. clear the [admin] section in your */etc/couchdb/local.ini
2. delete the _users.couch database (located in */var/lib/couchdb/)

This will reset the user database to factory defaults (admin party!) and wipe all of couchdb's user accounts. There might be a more subtle way

Comment: Works great, thanks a lot. A word of WARNING: This is very useful for development and test databases without any real users. If you do this on a production database all your user accounts will be gone, which is a BAD thing ;)

Comment: I did that, how do i restart the couchdb now. It still says you are not an admin when trying to restart db using curl

Answer (score 18):

With Apache CouchDB, admin accounts passwords can be changed by editing a file **local.ini** in the CouchDB config folder (**/etc/couchdb/** on most Linux installs). [[1]](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-user/201105.mbox/%3C7EB3BC3FA0DE4D4CB75746AF7F0100DF@rgabostyle.com%3E)

Look for the `[admin]` section, which will list the all admin usernames, along with their hashed passwords:

```
[admin]
foo = -pbkdf2-0e0e83f911c970565fc988497a657bdc21a005e8,19ecef0bea1caf8d7f08fb791379c686,10
```

Replace the password hash with a new clear text password:

```
foo = bar
```

Now restart CouchDB (`sudo restart couchdb` on Ubuntu). CouchDB will notice the clear text password on startup and automatically replace it with the hashed version.

Answer (score 6):

What I've done it's quite simple. I found out my old username and password here:

```
/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/config/config.dat
```

After that I went to `opt/couchbase/bin/` and run

```
./couchbase-cli cluster-init -c localhost:8091 -u old_user -p old_password --cluster-init-username=new_user --cluster-init-password=new_password
```

Done!
Also you can check this: http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-faq.html

Comment: With welcome! If it solve your problem, you can accept this answer :)

Comment: i forgot both id as well as password so what should i do ?

Comment: Couchbase is not exactly the same thing as CouchDB.

Answer (score 3):

For mac users, base folder is /Library/Application Support/couchdb

Comment: Or more likely  `~/Library/Application Support/couchdb`, unless you installed CouchDB as root

Comment: And if you used Homebrew to install it, the local.ini is at `/usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini`.

Answer (score 2):

One more point to add ...

If you are running Couch DB on Windows, then probably it was installed as a service and to reset it you need to stop service first, within running service other answers do not work.

http://www.7tutorials.com/what-are-windows-services-what-they-do-how-manage-them

Open *Control Panel - Administrative Tools - Services* and stop *Apache Couch DB*

Answer (score 1):

for Unix: 
http://silviud.blogspot.com/2012/10/couchbase-recover-web-console-password.html

```
/opt/couchbase/bin/erl \
-noinput -eval \
'case file:read_file("/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/config/config.dat") of {ok, B}  ->     io:format("~p~n", [binary_to_term(B)]) end.' \
-run init stop | grep cred
```

Comment: This one worked for retrieving my current password without resetting. Thanks ConAim.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the username and password in CouchDB local.ini file. You can add as many administrators as you want.

**sudo nano /etc/couchdb/local.ini**

and in the end of file, add username and password.

And don't forget to restart the CouchDB server.
**sudo service couchdb restart**

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X, `cbreset_password` is not in PATH by default, so I've done just:

```
"/Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin/cbreset_password" 127.0.0.1:8091
```

...and re-set the password once confirming `yes`

Comment: The cli has since been removed and replaced with `couchbase-cli`. Use this one instead, supply "newpassword": 
`$>  /Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin/couchbase-cli reset-admin-password --new-password newpassword`

Answer (score 0):

You can change couchbase localhost password by using following steps:
1. Install crul(for windows)
2. curl -u Administrator:password http://localhost:8091/controller/changePassword -d password=admin123

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu 20.04 :

```
apt purge couchdb

apt install couchdb
```

was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If using **3.2**, CouchDB server administrators and passwords in the last `[admins]` section that CouchDB finds when loading its ini files:

- `/opt/couchdb/etc/local.ini` or
- `/opt/couchdb/etc/local.d/10-admins.ini`

Don't forget to restart CouchDB:
`sudo systemctl restart couchdb` (if using ubuntu)

source: https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.0/config/auth.html