# How to Get CouchDB Username and Password

Tags: authentication, couchdb, couchdb-futon

Unfortunately I forgot what my username and password is to login to CouchDB.

Here is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765809/forgot-username-pwd-to-couchdb) question.

I have looked within the `local.ini` file at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\CouchDB\etc\couchdb`

```
password = somepassword
username = password
```

However I am unable to login through `lclhst` `:5984/_utils/index.html` login.

I have also tried the config.dat file at `/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/config/config.dat`

Are there other places where the username or password could be? It seems there is a hierarchy of files that take precedence over each other, though I could not find this in the docs.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your server credentials are in the `local.ini` whose full path can be found using `couchdb -c`, in the `[admins]` section, but the password is hashed. It looks like this:

```
[admins]
username = -pbkdf2-70349775b6e7674de7fd45ff08675550046535c9,f18db0cd9fd933c0c610532e965ef1de,10
```

If you forgot the password, just replace the hash with your new password and restart CouchDB. It will be rehashed immediately. Example:

```
[admins]
username = newPassw0rd
```

Answer (score 1):

relay from: http://silviud.blogspot.com/2012/10/couchbase-recover-web-console-password.html
(Note: top 4 lines only)

```
/opt/couchbase/bin/erl \
-noinput -eval \
'case file:read_file("/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/config/config.dat") of {ok, B}  ->         io:format("~p~n", [binary_to_term(B)]) end.' \
-run init stop | grep cred
```

Comment: I think this is for couchbase only. At least I could not find the config.dat here.