# How to recover CouchDB Futon Password on WIndows

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I installed CouchDB on my `Windows Machine` and after setting it up for the first time, I forgot the password. Now I can't login again in the Futon console. Is there any way to recover (or change) the password?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forgot Username / Pwd to CouchDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765809/forgot-username-pwd-to-couchdb)

Comment: My problem is exactly related to Windows Platform. All the answers to the question you have mentioned are for Linux/Mac OS.

Comment: But the same directory structure is present on Windows. Find your CouchDB installation folder and you should have a **var** folder.